# Compare only time in datetime to string in form HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a column in pandas df with string datetime like below

```
a,dtime
1,2017-07-06 09:15:00
1,2017-07-06 10:15:00
```

I am writing a script that needs to compare time

I need to compare like `df[df.dtime < "10:15:00"]` (without date)
So I converted `df['dtime']=pd.to_datetime(df['dtime'])`
If I do

```
df[df.dtime < "10:15:00"]
```

it takes today date as default and would always compare with today's "10:15:00" what I don't want.

So I created another column and then did it like below

```
df['ts']=df.dtime.apply(lambda x: x.time())
df[df.ts<"09:16:00"]
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to str
df[df.ts<pd.to_datetime("09:16:00").time()] #this works well
```

Is there a better way to do this simple task, I dont see any point creating a new ts column.

When I do 
`df['dtime']=pd.to_datetime(df['dtime'])` I should only extract time part. But doing `df['dtime']=pd.to_datetime(df['dtime']).time()` gives error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'`

Comment: Now you have changed your question and also the error.

Comment: This question was posted less than 7 mins ago, I fixed formatting and typo also added some more details. In no way question has been changed. There is way to check what edits have been made to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `time` or `timedelta` instead of `datetime`. You can access it vie the [`.dt.` methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties)

```
t = pd.to_datetime('10:15:00').time()
```

> `df['dtime'].dt.time < t`

```
0    True
1    False
Name: dtime, dtype: bool
```